# re.sub replace hexadecimal with string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, hex

I have a file that contains hexadecimal numbers that I want to convert to strings:

```
'\x73\x63\x6f\x72\x65\x73': '\x4c\x6f\x72\x65\x6d\x20\x69\x70\x73\x75\x6d',
'Status', ['\x75\x70\x64\x61\x74\x65']
```

But when using re.sub to replace each occurrence of a hexadecimal escaped number by its ascii representation, it doesn't seem to find the hexadecimal number in the first place.
I've tried using raw strings, but it didn't change anything. I still can't replace them.

````
import re, binascii
with open('hex.txt', 'r') as f:
    file = f.read()
    hexList = re.findall(r"'([\\x\w+]*)'", file)

    for item in hexList:
        file = re.sub(r"('{}')".format(item), str(binascii.unhexlify(item.replace('\\x', ''))), file)
        #file = re.sub("('"+item+"')".format(item), str(binascii.unhexlify(item.replace('\\x', ''))), file)
    print(file)```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code fragment

```
import re, binascii
with open('hex.txt', 'r') as f:
    file = f.read()
    hexList = re.findall(r'((?:\\x[0-9a-f][0-9a-f])+)', file)

    for item in hexList:
        file = re.sub(r"('{}')".format(item.replace('\\', '\\\\')), str(binascii.unhexlify(item.replace('\\x', ''))), file)
    print(file)
```

The regex used by you for finding the hex-strings is wrong because it is even finding the `Status` as the hex-string.